# How Can I Convert a List (from Collect) Into a String

Tags: string, list, neo4j, cypher

Using CYPHER I can get an ordered list of things using the collect() function. Is it possible to convert such a list into a simple string so that it behaves as a single string object?

If this isn't possible is it possible to somehow concatenate sequentially the contents of two (or more) collect statements so that in a single row I can produce output such as 'A,B,C a,b,c' where A,B,C is the ordered product of the 1st collect statement and a,b, c the second?

Comment: I think you should check out the reduce() function in cypher.

Answer (score 4):

To flesh out Dave's comment: First, you'll want to combine your collections, then use `REDUCE()` to append each item to a string. Like so:

```
WITH COLLECT(first_group) AS a, COLLECT(second_group) AS b
WITH a + b AS c
WITH REDUCE(s = HEAD(c), n IN TAIL(c) | s + ', ' + n) AS result
RETURN result
```

Check out [the docs](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.0/cypher/#functions-reduce) on `REDUCE` to get a better idea how it works in Cypher.

Answer (score 0):

A more general solution that will also work for collections of objects (not just collections of strings) is to convert the concatenated collections into **stringified JSON** using the [APOC](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures) procedure [apoc.convert.toJson](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_from_tojson).

This example using string collections:

```
WITH ['A','B','C'] AS x, ['a','b','c'] AS y, ['do','re','mi'] AS z
WITH x + y + z AS data
CALL apoc.convert.toJson(data) YIELD value
RETURN value
```

will return this:

```
"[\"A\",\"B\",\"C\",\"a\",\"b\",\"c\",\"do\",\"re\",\"mi\"]"
```

This example using object collections:

```
WITH [{a:1},{b:2},{c:3}] AS x, [{a:10},{b:20},{c:30}] AS y, [{a:100},{b:200},{c:300}] AS z
WITH x + y + z AS data
CALL apoc.convert.toJson(data) YIELD value
RETURN value
```

will return this:

```
"[{\"a\":1},{\"b\":2},{\"c\":3},{\"a\":10},{\"b\":20},{\"c\":30},{\"a\":100},{\"b\":200},{\"c\":300}]"
```